# Continuation Point (session.Browse) returns null while browsing nodes from OPC UA server

Tags: c#, opc-ua

I am trying to browse nodes from OPC UA server using session.

```
BrowseContext browseContext = new BrowseContext()
{
    BrowseDirection = BrowseDirection.Forward,
    IncludeSubtypes = true,
    ReferenceTypeId = ReferenceTypeIds.References,
};

Byte[] cp = null;
List<ReferenceDescription> objectTypeNodes = session.Browse(ObjectTypeIds.BaseObjectType, browseContext, new RequestSettings() { OperationTimeout = 10000 }, out cp);
```

But my continuation point is returning null.
Kindly help.

Answer (score 1):

That's exactly what it is supposed to return. It means that you got all references and there is nothing to continue with.

If you get a continuation point, then you must call BrowseNext to get the next set of references.

Comment: For example references-> hierarchical references->has child ->xxx->xxx.Here am not able to fetch all nodes the continuation point value is null,even though hierarchical references has child nodes.

Comment: So what does your list of ReferenceDescriptions contain (i.e. objectsFolder as you have named it) for this query?

Comment: I have edited the code.please check.here it returns all base object types.i have my own object types which has sub references under it.but am not able to fetch these sub references.

Comment: Yes, you only get the immediate references from the node that you browse (sub types in this case). To browse further down, you will need to make new browse requests recursively from the previous results.

Comment: what is the advantages and disadvantages of nodemanagement(adding,deleting from client side) in opcua ?

Comment: It enables the client to modify the server address space, for example to add new data points, which may be good. But it may be bad, if you let anyone do it without restrictions. (BTW: better to open new issues for new questions, so other people will also find your questions)